# How to rerun an Airflow task with different arguments if the task fails

Tags: python, airflow, jira, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a Airflow DAG, which has a task for jira creation through jira operator.
In case the jira creation fails, I want to rerun the task with different set of arguments.

I tried to check the status of jira creation task with a BranchPythonOperator and if the task fails I am pushing new arguments to xcom.

```
def get_jira_status(**kwargs):
    context = kwargs
    failed_tasks_found = False
    dag_run = context['dag_run']
    dag_id = context["dag"].dag_id
    ti = context['task_instance']
    curr_tid = ti.task_id
    for task_instance in dag_run.get_task_instances():
        if 'create_jira' in str(task_instance):
            t_state = task_instance.current_state()
            tid = task_instance.task_id
            if t_state == 'failed':
                failed_tasks_found = True
    if not failed_tasks_found:
        return "success"
        
    jira_args=ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_tasks_status', key='jira_args')
    if 'xyz' in str(jira_args):
        del jira_args['xyz']
    ti.xcom_push(key='jira_args', value=jira_args)
    return "create_jira"
```

But from BranchPythonOperator how do I call the upstream task (jira creation task)
If I do `branch_task >> [rerun_upstream_task, continue_downstream_tasks]`.
Airflow showing error `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cycle detected in DAG`.